# Envío de correo con copia PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, email

Realizo un modulo en el cual los usuario al tener algún incidente de trabajo lo reportan llenándolo, este a su vez lo inserta en la BD y lo envía al correo que le coloco como principal  `$to = 'soporte.it@gmail.com';`,  lo que necesito es que también  le envié una copia del correo al usuario que inicio sesión  con el campo `$user_id = $_SESSION["user_id"];`.

```
<?php   
session_start();
/*Inicia validacion del lado del servidor*/
if ( empty($_POST['title']) ) {
  $errors[] = "Descripción vacío";
}
else if ( !empty($_POST['title']) ){

  include "../config/config.php";//Contiene funcion que conecta a la base de datos

  $title = $_POST["title"];
  $user_id = $_SESSION["user_id"];
  $category_id = $_POST["combo3"]; 
  $priority_id = $_POST["priority_id"];     
  $area_id = $_POST["combo1"];
  $final_id = $_POST["combo2"];
  $subcategoria_id = $_POST["combo4"];
  $created_at="NOW()";

  // $user_id=$_SESSION['user_id'];

  $sql="insert into ticket
  (title,user_id,category_id,priority_id,area_id,final_id,subcategoria_id,created_at) 
  value 
  (\"$title\",\"$user_id\",\"$category_id\",$priority_id,$area_id,$final_id,$subcategoria_id,$created_at)";

  $query_new_insert = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
  if ($query_new_insert){
    $messages[] = "Tu ticket ha sido ingresado satisfactoriamente.";
    echo'<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location.href="tickets.php";
    </script>';

  } else{
    $errors []= "Lo siento algo ha salido mal intenta nuevamente.".mysqli_error($con);
  }
} else {
  $errors []= "Error desconocido.";
}

if (isset($errors)){

  ?>
  <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close"  data-dismiss="alert">&times; </button>
    <strong>Error!</strong> 
    <?php
    foreach ($errors as $error) {
      echo $error;
    }
    ?>

  </div>
  <?php
}
if ( isset($messages) ) {

  ?>
  <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close"  data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    <strong>¡Bien hecho!</strong>
    <?php
    foreach ($messages as $message) {
      echo $message;
    }
    ?>  
  </div>
  <?php
}


htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);

$sql= "Select t.title, 
are.name are_desc,
fin.name fin_desc,
cat.name cat_desc,
sub.name sub_desc,
pri.name pri_desc,

FROM
ticket t

LEFT JOIN area are ON are.id = t.area_id  
LEFT JOIN final fin ON fin.id = t.final_id 
LEFT JOIN category cat ON cat.id = t.category_id 
LEFT JOIN sub_categoria sub ON sub.id = t.subcategoria_id  
LEFT JOIN priority pri ON pri.id = t.priority_id ";

$title = $_POST['title'];
$user_id = $_SESSION["user_id"];
$area_id = $_POST['combo1'];
$final_id = $_POST['combo2'];
$category_id = $_POST["combo3"];
$subcategoria_id = $_POST["combo4"];
$priority_id = $_POST["priority_id"];


$to = 'soporte.it@gmail.com';

if (isset($_POST["submit"]) && $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  $title = test_input($_POST["title"]);
  $user_id = test_input($_SESSION["user_id"]);
  $area_id = test_input($_POST["combo1"]);
  $final_id = test_input($_POST["combo2"]);
  $category_id = test_input($_POST["combo3"]);
  $subcategoria_id = test_input($_POST["combo4"]);
  $priority_id= test_input($_POST["priority_id"]);
}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}

$cabeceras = 'From: ' . " " . $final_id . "\r\n";
$cabeceras .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8";

$msjCorreo = "<img src='C:/xampp/htdocs/tickets.usuarios/images/logo.jpg'>



<center><h3><strong>Sistema de Registro de Incidencias</strong></h3></center>

<center>Para nosotros es un placer asistirle el día de hoy, a continuación le brindamos la información correspondiente a su incidente. En un momento nuestro ingeniero de soporte en turno acudirá a su lugar de trabajo</center><br/><br/><br/>


<strong>Solicitud de Atención:</strong>" . $title;
$msjCorreo .= "<br /> <br />";

$msjCorreo .= "<strong>Área:</strong> " . $area_id;
$msjCorreo .= "<br /><br />";

$msjCorreo .= "<strong>Usuario Final:</strong> " . $final_id;
$msjCorreo .= "<br /><br />";

$msjCorreo .= "<strong>Categoría: </strong>" . $category_id;
$msjCorreo .= "<br /><br />";

$msjCorreo .= "<strong>Sub Categoria: </strong>" . $subcategoria_id;
$msjCorreo .= "<br /><br />";

$msjCorreo .= "<strong>Prioridad: </strong>" . $priority_id;
$msjCorreo .= "<br /><br /><br />";

$msjCorreo .= "

Gracias<br />
Departamento de Sistemas<br />
Teléfono: +52 222 418 3000  |  Ext. 137<br />

";
$msjCorreo .= "<br /><br />";


if (mail($to, "Nueva Solicitud de Atención", $msjCorreo, $cabeceras)) {
  echo'<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("¡Muchas gracias! Pulse aceptar, la información se ingreso correctamente y se envió por email.");
    window.location.href="tickets.php";
  </script>';
} else {
  echo "<script language='javascript'>
    alert('fallado');
  </script>";
}
```

Comment: Saludos, tal como comentaste en una de las respuestas debes primer ir a consultar el correo del usuario con esto como ya sabes agregar el "Cc" ..tambien te recomiendo donde haces la validacion del usuario el login de una vez asignar a una variable de session el correo del mismo y con esto evitas estar haciendo consultas futuras..

Comment: @DiegoAvila Ya modifique el código donde se le asigna una variable  de session, me podrías orientar de como realizar la consulta del correo que corresponde al usuario por favor, ya que he intentado de varias formas y no lo consigo

Answer (score 0):

Deberías de agregar despues de la linea **From:**

```
$cabeceras = 'From: ' . " " . $final_id . "\r\n";
$cabeceras .= 'Cc: '.$user_id.'\r\n';
```

O copia oculta:

```
$cabeceras .= 'BCc: '.$user_id.'\r\n';
```

Puedes recuperar el correo del user de la siguiente manera:

```
$query = "SELECT u.email as email FROM ticket t INNER JOIN user u ON u.id = t.user_id WHERE t.user_id = ".$id_user." order by t.user_id DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysql_error());
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($rows==1){
    $emailIdUser = $result['email'];
    $cabeceras .= 'BCc: '.$emailIdUser .'\r\n';
 }else{
    $emailIdUser = "Sin email";
 }
```

Comment: estimado gracias por responder, tengo una duda respecto al código que me enviaste ya que los usuarios que se registran (nombre, correo, etc) están en una tabla foránea y en mi tabla donde se inserta todas las incidencias es aparte ahí solo se inserta el ID (que es el numero de control del trabajador) entonces supongo que ¿hay que hacer un llamado al correo del usuario para que le llegue la copia del correo?

Comment: @Carlos Claro, deberías de consultar el email del usuario, no sé en que tabla lo guardas, pero con un `SELECT email FROM tu-table WHERE id_usuario = $id_user` estaría listo para obtener el e-mail y usarlo como **cc:**

Comment: agregue en la linea que envía la copia del correo `$cabeceras .= 'Bcc: ' . "SELECT t.user_id,u.email  FROM ticket t INNER JOIN user u ON u.id = t.user_id order by t.user_id DESC LIMIT 1" . "\r\n";` pero me arroja este error `Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 553 Invalid RFC821 mailbox specification. in line 212`

Comment: Pues está mal. Eso es solo un string, deberías de recuperar el correo como lo recuperas antes del form cuando haces `$_SESSION['correo']` (o se lo pasas mediante el form para no tener que volver a reconsultar la BD)

Comment: Edité mi respuesta para que veas el ejemplo.

Comment: modifique mi código como lo tengo hasta ahora con Bcc (copia oculta), según yo así se amolda a mi código pero ahora ya no me envía ningún correo

Comment: Pues no veo el nuevo codigo de Bcc... edita tu pregunta por que no puedo adivinar que es lo que estás haciendo....

Comment: listo ya edite mi codigo como lo tengo

Comment: Sigo sin verlo, has editado tu pregunta? sigue igual.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95045/discussion-between-carlos-and-roy).

Answer (score 0):

existen diferentes posibles respuestas voy agregar un ejemplo breve:

1.- Agregar el correo del usuario en el momento de validar el login a **SESSION**:

**Mi tabla ejemplo:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `usuarios` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `usuario` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `correo` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `clave` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 );
```

conexion a DB(**db.php**):

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","123456","prueba");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Falla al conectar a MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
?>
```

**login.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Login</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<?php
require('db.php');
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['usuario'])){
    $usuario = stripslashes($_REQUEST['usuario']);
    $usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$usuario);
    $clave = stripslashes($_REQUEST['usuario']);
    $clave = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$clave);
    //verifico el usuario
    $query = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario='$username'and   clave='".md5($clave)."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysql_error());
    $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if($rows==1){
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
        $_SESSION['correo'] = $result['correo'];
        //redirijo a mi pagina index.php
        header("Location: index.php");
         }else{
    echo "<div class='form'>
<h3>Usuario/clave is incorrectos.</h3>
<br/>Click aqui para <a href='login.php'>Iniciar Sesion</a></div>";
    }
    }else{
?>
<div class="form">
<h1>Log In</h1>
<form action="" method="post" name="login">
<input type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuario" required />
<input type="password" name="clave" placeholder="Clave" required />
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Acceder" />
</form>
</div>
<?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Bien con esto si te fijas ya tienes asignado el correo del usuario a **SESSION**
con esto puedes acceder de la siguiente manera a este:

```
$_SESSION["correo"]
```

ahora solo resta que eso agregues para la copia de tu correo.

Answer (score 0):

Lo mas fácil es: 
Si coges el "to" de un hidden o donde lo cojas simplemente separa por comas a los usuarios que los quieras enviar
Este envia a los dos usuarios:

```
<input type="hidden" value="correodelaempresa@prueba.com,correodelusuario@prueba.com" name="to" id="to" />
```

y este en contrario envia solo a la empresa

```
 <input type="hidden" value="correodelaempresa@prueba.com" name="to" id="to" />
```

Si es un valor fijo, haces igual, separas por comas a los destinatarios:

```
$to = 'soporte.it@gmail.com,correodelusuario@prueba.com';
```

Comment: el problema es que se tiene que enviar automaticamente el correo solo al usuario que lleno el formulario que se inserto en la tabla ticket (con el campo user_id)

Comment: pero el usuario tendra un correo asociado no? simplemente lo sacas con una consulta y lo pones en el to tambien

Comment: asi es el usuario tiene un correo alojado en la tabla user, he tratado de hacerlo esta es mi consulta `SELECT t.user_id,u.email  FROM ticket t INNER JOIN user u ON u.id = t.user_id` no se como meterlo en el to

Comment: sacas el resultado de la consulta que sera el u.email $to = 'soporte.it@gmail.com

Comment: @Ke TeMeTo modifique el codigo con la cosulta añadiendola al to... ¿así esta bien?

Comment: pero en el $to= 'soporte.it@gmail.com,$elresultadodelcorreodelsuario'; y te lo deberia enviar sin problemas. Tienes ya en una variable el correo del usuario que relleno el ticket?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95008/discussion-between-carlos-and-ketemeto).